# How can I make every child process get a different client address (UDP SOCKET)?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, fork

I have a problem : 
        - For every message the client sends, the server creates a child process (fork()) and every single message is read by a different child.
        The question : 
        -  Is there any way I could erase the sockaddr_in structure , so that when the server goes one again in the infinite loop, it would wait for a different client and every child would have a different address for a client.

```
A part of the server code:

    struct sockaddr_in from;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
            int32_t stringLen;
            initSocket();
            printf("waiting for a connection\n");
            while (true) {
                int n;
                socklen_t length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                n = recvfrom(sock, &stringLen, sizeof(stringLen), 0,
                        (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length);
                if (n > 0) {
                    int pid = fork();
                    printf("fork() pid = %d\n", pid);
                    if (pid < 0) {
                        error("handling request");
                    }
                    if (pid == 0) {
                        printf("Client connected...\n");
                        handle_request(stringLen);
                    }
                    cout << " PID : " << pid << endl;
                }
            }
        }

Thank you !
```

Comment: `from` gets filled by `recvfrom()` indicating who sent the data. Why do you want to clear it out?

Comment: that was my ideea too. I tried clearing it out with memcpy ( &from, 0, sizeof(from) ); .. but it doesn't work. Every message that I intend to send to a single child is read by multiple ones.

Comment: `from` **is not a filter** from which client to read from. And: You are using **the same socket for each child**, so what is being received by `sock` is read by the child-process which is first. The `fork()` duplicates the socket `sock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment: Reading is done by all processes on the same socket, as the latter is duplicated when `fork()`ing.

You'd be better off letting the parent read the whole message and then `fork()` off the child passing the message read and then start over reading the next message.

Comment: Is there any way of avoiding that - making the child read all the message and not to block the parent ?

Comment: @IulianRosca: Using only one socket, only one process should do the read. Otherwise the processes doing multiple parallel reads would be in the need to communicated with each other to perform some sort of synchronisation to block each other until each read its message entirly. Which brings no gain compared to letting the parent do the read of each an every message, but complications implementing the synchronisation. To conclude: The messages arrive sequentially, so why not read them one by one?

Comment: @IulianRosca: Or should it be a client is intended to send **more then one message** to a child processe?

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks A lot , I would really like to rate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If fork() creates new processes, synchronization operation can be undertaken simply by a file IO. By reading and writing to the same configuration file, child processes can get the available socket address from a file

Comment: I need to use child processes.

Comment: Please, what exactly do you mean by "*available socket number*"?

Comment: just changed to socket address

Comment: I still do not get what you mean? It is not possible to exchange memory addresses between processes.

Comment: as a turnaround, it is possible if they use a shared file location

Comment: Sure, you could use shared lock-files to implement some sort of synchronisation. The question is what you gain in the OP's setup, if you 1st create a mess by distributing a serial data stream by coping socket descriptors due to calls to fork() and 2ndly later try to clean up the mess by synchronising the concurrent access to the copied sockets with the intend to serialise again what you distributed beforehand, what originally had been a stream?